# When to use proxy and when to use CORS in a react project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am a beginner at react development, I am confused about when I should use proxy or cors to make the front end talk to the back end.. Or do i need to use both? like proxy for development and cors for production?

Comment: You don't need CORS (or a proxy) for your own back end, since it's the same origin, and CORS is Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.

Comment: They are different tools that suit different needs.  Sometimes you need both, sometimes you need neither.  Please add to your question what purpose you think they both serve, your use case, and why you think you need either.  The way your question is phrased right now is too broad.

Comment: The way you have phrased your question, we would need to answer "What is CORS?", "What is a proxy?", "What service do both of those serve?".  Your question needs to be narrowed.

Answer (score 3):

CORS is completely related to back end when you want make your back end server accessible for any request use CORS.

example:

```
const app=require('express');
const cors=require('cors');
app.use(cors())// server will respond to any domain
```

Most of the time you are going to use a proxy when you want to be able to connect to an api that the webpack dev server isn't hosting but will be hosted by your server when published. An example will probably clear this up better than anything.

When developing you have the following scenario

API Server - running at localhost:4567 Webpack Dev Server - running at localhost:8080

Your App.js will make a request to the API server like so

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/getOwnedGames',
    ...
});
```

Without a proxy this will actually make a request to localhost:8080/api/getOwnedGames (since you are browsing from the webpack dev server). If you however setup the proxy like so...

```
proxy: {
    '/api/*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:4567'
    }
}
```

the api request will get rewritten to be http://localhost:4567/api/getOwnedGames.

if you aren't hosting your own api you probably don't need the proxy.